# How to stop my div, from resizing downwards in height?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm trying to get `.wrap` DIV to stay within the height of the `.Section 3` DIV. It's been frustrating me for weeks now and I can't find help for this problem anywhere.

[image] `.Section 3` consists of the "Macbook/iPhone img" and the "little white bit" below it. The top of the img is exactly inline with the top of the DIV '.Section 3'. But the img base isn't inline with the DIV `.Section 3` Base. When the window gets wider, the img height gets longer (Downwards) & ends up overlapping the next DIV Section (YELLOW BIT).

Usually I would put the img in through CSS, but because the img is animated with a slideshow displaying on the screen of the Macbook and iPhone screens. I can only have it through HTML

Heres the Code:

```css
.Section3{
  height: 500px !important;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 500px !important;
  padding-top: 40%; /* ratio of image * 100 */
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.mockup {
  position: absolute ;
  top: -180px;
  overflow:hidden;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.mockup::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(209,157,84,0.09);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.mockup__img {
  display: block;
  width: 1900px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Section3" class="Section3" role="main">
  <div id="wrap" class="wrap">
    <div class="mockup">
      <img class="mockup__img" src="I M A G E S/Portfolio Work/MacbookiPhone BG.jpg"/>
      <div class="mobile">
        <ul id="slideshow-1" class="slideshow">
          <li class="slideshow__item"><img src="I M A G E S/Portfolio Work/small/1.png"/></li>
          <li class="slideshow__item"><img src="I M A G E S/Portfolio Work/small/2.png"/></li>
          <li class="slideshow__item"><img src="I M A G E S/Portfolio Work/small/3.png"/></li>
          <li class="slideshow__item"><img src="I M A G E S/Portfolio Work/small/4.png"/></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="screen">
        <ul id="slideshow-2" class="slideshow">
          <li class="slideshow__item current"><img src="I M A G E S/Portfolio Work/large/1.png"/></li>
          <li class="slideshow__item"><img src="I M A G E S/Portfolio Work/large/2.png"/></li>
          <li class="slideshow__item"><img src="I M A G E S/Portfolio Work/large/3.png"/></li>
          <li class="slideshow__item"><img src="I M A G E S/Portfolio Work/large/4.png"/></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused on what your overall objective is. To get the image flush w/ the navigation??  "I'm trying to get one of my DIV's, to stay within the height of the Section DIV" - I'm assuming the "Section DIV" is the `#Section3`

Comment: I suggest that you use a slider/carousel plugin than creating a custom one.

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle/jsbin page and share url here.